# MySQL how to select multiple rows by foreign key id?

Tags: mysql

Surveys table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecLVX.png)

Questions table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJsxp.png)

My sql query:

> SELECT s.id, q.question
> FROM questions q
> JOIN surveys s ON q.surveyId = s.id;

My results:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "question": "Which industry are you working at?"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "question": "What is your company's highest annual revenue?"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "question": "How long has your company been operated? updated"
    }
]
```

But I want this output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "questions": [
            "Which industry are you working at?",
            "What is your company's highest annual revenue?",
            "How long has your company been operated?"
        ]
    }
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG356.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [GROUP BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

```
SELECT 
  s.id, 
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(q.question)
FROM 
  questions q 
JOIN 
  surveys s ON q.surveyId = s.id;
GROUP BY
  s.id
```

This will probably get quite close to what you want, however you need MySQL 8.0.14 or later. Have a look at [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg). Other aggregation functions could be used but then you need to do some work on the result.

The `GROUP BY` is essential though.